# jQuery accordion shows more page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

Hi i am trying to implement jQuery accordion dynamically it works but each accordion 
  contains expandable data it shows more page previously that means before expand the data 
  can any body please help me iam trying autoheight also.
   Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me, but could you at least post your code?

Comment: my code is nearly 200 lines and i am using php you dont have any problem i will post

Comment: Don't show us all 200 lines, just show us the part that isn't working that you are trying to get working

Comment: Accordion action is fine it calculates height dynamically and show all the page at an instance

Comment: <div id="accordion" class="intrv">

Comment: Put your code in your question and use the formatting tool.